# Kivy can post info to server in kivy.launcher,but useless from apk file(same code). some suggestions?

Tags: android, http-post, kivy, urllib

I wrote a small app with kivy, its functionality is very simple, In the UI, your can type your name and tap Submit button, then my app is connected to a cloud server, whenever you tap Submit, It can receive what your write in the app, it's useful in PC（I run in my terminal and I can receive what you typed in  the cloud server）, also in kivy.launcher（I put app.main and .kv in my android device, I also can receive information in server）; but when I use buildozer to build it into a .apk file, it runs on my android device, but when I tap Submit button, I could't receive anything in my cloud server, both in wifi and 3g/4g, did somebody know what is wrong with my app?
Thanks for your reply and suggestions. I'm a newbie, so I can not upload img.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your APK has the INTERNET permission (you can enable this in buildozer.spec).

Comment: I have delete the "#" before the INTERNET, but it doesn't work.                       such like this "
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET", for other Android specific, I didn't modify.